# Binding ListView Field to Value in Code-Behind

Tags: asp.net, listview, webforms

I'm displaying fields from a DB call in a ListView. I had to re-code my database query because of an issue with repeating groups. I also didn't want to have to deal with nested ListViews. So now I am trying to set the header to the value of radio button list selection. I was trying to write a custom method to return that value but could not remember the syntax.

How can I set the header in the LayoutTemplate from the code-behind so that it doesn't repeat?

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <div class="resultsGrid">
        <strong><%# GetHeader() %></strong>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="resultsPlaceHolder">
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    // rest of data
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this as follows:

```
<asp:ListView ID="resultsList" ItemPlaceholderID="resultsPlaceHolder"
    OnItemCreated="ResultsList_ItemCreated" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="resultsGrid">
            <strong><asp:Label ID="headerLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label></strong>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="resultsPlaceHolder">
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        // rest of data
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
protected void ResultsList_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is ListViewItem)
    {
        Label tempLabel = resultsList.FindControl("headerLabel") as Label;
        tempLabel.Text = ViewState["ParkName"].ToString();
    }
}
```